# How to pass enum From ListView to ContentView constructs in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to accept in the enum constructor and depending on what value comes there, display a specific element

I have such a constructor:

```
public class AssetStatusView : ContentView
{
    public AssetStatusView(AssetRecordStatus status)
    {
        var label = new Label
        {
            Text = status.ToString().SplitCamelCase(),//Here I get text depend on status
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        var frame = new Frame
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(GetHex(status)), //Here I get color depend on status
            HasShadow = false,
            CornerRadius = 5,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Content = label
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
               frame,
            }
        };
    }
 }
```

Here is an example of a ListView from which I need to pass enum values ​​to the parameter:

```
<ListView x:Name="assetRecords"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AssetRecords}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    
                    <local:AssetStatusView>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:AssetRecordStatus></x:AssetRecordStatus>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </local:AssetStatusView>
                    
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You need to try bindable property concept .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Comment: I know about it, I also tried it, but this is not the behavior I want. I want to pass directly to the constructor

Comment: You're going to run into problems with this approach. Because every item in the ListView uses the same item template, anything you try to pass as an argument to the ctor of AssetStatusView will get passed to each item, which seems pointless. While I don't know your use case, it sounds like this may be a good place to use a converter or a data template selector.

Comment: I'm new to xamarin, I want to make an element with certain text and color depending on the value. Can you point me in that direction? I want something like "if else"

Comment: I added what exactly I am doing in the constructor, maybe this will make my goal clearer

Comment: Please check this approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector